# Decoupling auth module in microservices

Tags: architecture, microservices, separation-of-concerns

We started working on a project recently where we had to build functionality around auth and users. We decided on dividing the responsibilities as :

User service

- keeping user entity
- user related crud operations

user entity will have basic fields like
User

- userId
- first name
- last name
- dob
- email
- phone number

And auth service will have functionalities like :

- login user
- signup user
- generate and validate tokens (JWTs)

auth services contains the entity for storing credentials for a given userId

problem statement :

For some reason we feel we are doing something wrong. Because lets say we would like the user to login through emailId/password. so we could think of 2 approaches :

1 - when user tries to login using phone or email, it directly hits auth service (ignoring gateway for now). Now auth service simply contains userId and password, so it needs to translate the given emailId/phone to userId. So it calls user service and brings the user data as per emilId/phone number, Then it checks if the userId and corresponding password matched. If so, it returns user data and JWT.

But this somehow semantically feels wrong to bring the user details first from user service and then authenticating.

2 - The UI calls user service with given emailId/phone number and password. user service does the translation of email/phone to userId,then sends the userid/password to auth service. On successful authentication it auth service sends the auth token back to user service, user service adds user details to this response and sends back to UI

Can anyone please suggest that which approach seems to be better or if there isa better design to do the same

Comment: I'm not experienced with Microservices, but I think you could use a Shared Database for both if you keep communicating between the 2 services just for a single request. Share the Database or just combine them cause it's seem too fine-grained here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you put too much focus on the "micro" in the term microservices. In your example there is nothing that would justify the existence of a "user" service to me.

When thinking about service boundaries in a microservices design the task is not to make every service as small as possible. The boundaries should be cut along the lines of what a useful function in the business domain is (and what can be maintained by a [two-pizza team](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/apr/24/the-two-pizza-rule-and-the-secret-of-amazons-success)). In your case the only function you describe is authentication, so that would only justify a single service.

Another word on writing your own auth module/service - There are existing open source solutions that you can use (the most widely used being [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)). That is free to use and battle tested for security. It just happens too easily to introduce serious security flaws in your own implementation. Also you would get a rich feature set that would take many years to implement on your own.

Comment: we segregated user service and auth because they both may develop further independently. And as a practice I feel mostly its suggested to keep auth module separate, so we planned to keep auth module separate.

Comment: It is still not clear to me what this user service would be representing, but nevertheless it is very common that multiple services represent different domain aspects/views onto a user. In these cases each of the services only holds the domain specific data and you use the user ID as a link. In your example, the auth service would still require pretty much everything you describe in your scenario.

Comment: user service would be representing user related crud operations, like creating a new user, updating its attributes, deleting, updating status, etc ....

Comment: you need to do that for every view onto the user, or any data anyway, for example for the auth related user data. So that in itself is not a useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not split those two in most cases (based on your description they seems to be quite tightly coupled), but if you still feel the need to then you are forgetting the 3rd option which is a backbone of the microservices approach - data duplication - you store a copy of everything identity-related in the auth service (like email, external system ids, etc.) and sync it from the user service asynchronously (via message broker).

In general you will want to reduce the number of async calls between services in the microservices architecture and auth functionality seems one of the places where you will want to reduce number of hops (which will improve performance and reliability).